# Number is missing decimals so I need to add it

Tags: string

I have several numbers like the ones shown below that should have a decimal before the last 2 digits.  Is there a regular expression that can add a decimal before the last 2 digits?

373648
836374
247384

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these are coming from a variable, you should be able to use a variable modifier on them.

`{my_number:number_format decimals="2"}`

[Variable Modifier Documentation](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/variable-modifiers.html#number_format)

Comment: Thanks!  I tested in https://regex101.com/ and it’s giving me an error.

Comment: I apologize, my answer wasn't using regex, but rather assuming you were using EE variables and could just use a built un modifier.